# OpenLayers - how to add multiple points to layer

Tags: openlayers, point

I have two arrays, these are latitude and longitude coordinates

this works when I add 1 coordinate, but how i can add all coordinates?

```
var marker = new Feature(
          new Point([stringLongitude[0],stringLatitude[0]])
      );
```

Comment: Depends on what you trying to get. Do you want to get one feature for all points or as many features as points? The first case is to create a MultiPoint geometry. The second one is to create features in a loop with a Point geometry in each feature like in your example.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html)?

Comment: @Anatoly Do you have any example how to use MultiPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipoint is a class in Openlayers. Not having stated an explicit version I assume you work with the latest.

From the Openlayers documentation:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_MultiPoint-MultiPoint.html

The multipoint class may receive an array of lat lng

```
new MultiPoint([
  [lng, lat]
  [lng, lat], opt_layout)
```